# How to automate capturing screenshots for an iOS app

Tags: ios, screenshot

iTunes play store expects a few screen shots before the mobile application is published to the store. How to automate capturing screenshots for an iOS app, are there any tools available ?

Comment: Why automate? It's only 5 screens. Run your app. Go to a screen you want and take a screenshot. Use the Xcode organizer to make it even easier.

Comment: If you develop a single app the suggestion you make is fine. If you have to do this for 50+ apps on a daily basis, its preferable to automate. Sometimes world is too small from someones perspective and I get a freakin down-vote for this.

Comment: The down votes are because 1) You show no effort and 2) Posting questions looking for tools is off-topic.

Comment: I apologize, I should have mentioned it earlier and I just have no knowledge of the iOS framework and I am tasked in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF)?  It's an automation framework intended for testing, but it can also be used to get your app into the state you want for taking a screenshot.

Comment: Can you point me to the exact documentation on how to get the application into a certain state. FYI - I have no knowledge of iOS libraries, thanks for your answer.

Comment: It depends on the state you want your application to get into.  KIF lets you send taps, swipes, etc... to your application so that you can get it looking how you want; it's up to you to know how it is that you want it.